# Эффект нажатой/отпущенной кнопки

Tags: java, android

Эффект нажатия кнопки делаю так: файл `button.xml` в `drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_today_t" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_today_t" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_today_n" />
</selector>
```

И в кнопке соответственно `android:background="@drawable/button"`

Все работает как надо, но есть одно но, кнопка визуально становится нажатой через ~0.2сек после прикосновения. В принципе это происходит и без оформленной кнопки, даже с простой серой. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как то сделать, чтобы кнопка визуально нажималась в момент прикосновения? Спасибо.

**UPD**

```
    button_today.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                button_today.setPressed(true);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: попробуйте в onClickListener добавить строчку mButton.setPressed(true)

Comment: @KirillStoianov, ничего не поменялось

Comment: ну можно еще попробовать вместо onClickListener повесить OnTouchListener

Comment: @KirillStoianov, спасибо! Это помогло. Обновил первый пост. Оно то работает, только если так на каждую кнопку сделать код замусоривается)

Comment: @Pollux а не пробовали `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` ? по идее этот метод должен быстрее работать

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, не доводилось этот метод никогда использовать...

Comment: @Pollux я добавил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно создать один экземпляр `View.OnTouchListener` и присвоить его каждой кнопке:

```
View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                ((Button)findViewById(v.getId())).setPressed(true);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

 button_today.setOnTouchListener(listener);
 button_today2.setOnTouchListener(listener);
 button_today3.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

Comment: Сразу не проверил, чето не хочет сотрудничать код) Не получается поправить. [жмяк](http://i83.fastpic.ru/big/2016/0917/d9/f13fb3f947a29d1ee8078fec07dbe0d9.png)

Comment: изменил ответ, надо было так                 ((Button)findViewById(v.getId())).setPressed(true);